# Select Statement in website's Gridview not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I created a website in Visual Studio 2010.  On a webpage, I want to display date in gridview.  When I go to configure the data source, I used the query builder to get the data I want - namely, I want to display all records for the user that is currently logged into.  The user is determined from the Windows login.  My Select statement is:

```
SELECT tblWorkHours.EmployeeName, tblWorkHours.BeginDateOff, tblWorkHours.EndDateOff,    
tblWorkHours.AllDay_YesNo, tblWorkHours.BeginTimeOff, tblWorkHours.EndTimeOff,  
tblWorkHours.Approved, tblCodesWork.Description, tblEmployees.Login FROM tblWorkHours INNER JOIN 
tblCodesWork ON tblWorkHours.WorkCode = tblCodesWork.WorkCodeID INNER JOIN tblEmployees ON 
tblWorkHours.Employee = tblEmployees.EmployeeID WHERE (tblEmployees.Login = @username) ORDER BY 
tblWorkHours.BeginDateOff DESC
```

When I test the query in the Configure Data Source wizard, the query returns the correct data.  When I run the webpage, there is no gridview.  I have tried adding a field to the webpage to make sure that I am getting the correct user name, and that works.  What am I doing wrong?  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code for the webpage:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"   
CodeBehind="TimeOffAllByUser.aspx.vb" Inherits="timework.TimeOffAllByUser" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeName" HeaderText="EmployeeName" 
            SortExpression="EmployeeName">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BeginDateOff" 
            HeaderText="BeginDateOff" SortExpression="BeginDateOff">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EndDateOff" 
            HeaderText="EndDateOff" SortExpression="EndDateOff">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="AllDay_YesNo" HeaderText="AllDay_YesNo" 
            SortExpression="AllDay_YesNo">
        </asp:CheckBoxField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BeginTimeOff" 
            HeaderText="BeginTimeOff" SortExpression="BeginTimeOff">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EndTimeOff" 
            HeaderText="EndTimeOff" SortExpression="EndTimeOff">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Approved" HeaderText="Approved" 
            SortExpression="Approved">
        </asp:CheckBoxField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
            SortExpression="Description">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="Login" HeaderText="Login" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TimeSQLConnectionString1 %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT tblWorkHours.EmployeeName, tblWorkHours.BeginDateOff, 
    tblWorkHours.EndDateOff, tblWorkHours.AllDay_YesNo, tblWorkHours.BeginTimeOff, 
    tblWorkHours.EndTimeOff, tblWorkHours.Approved, tblCodesWork.Description, tblEmployees.Login 
    FROM tblWorkHours INNER JOIN tblCodesWork ON tblWorkHours.WorkCode = tblCodesWork.WorkCodeID 
    INNER JOIN tblEmployees ON tblWorkHours.Employee = tblEmployees.EmployeeID WHERE 
   (tblEmployees.Login = @username) ORDER BY tblWorkHours.BeginDateOff DESC" >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="username" 
            QueryStringField="Split(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, quot;\&quot;, ,  
            CompareMethod.Text)" 
            Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The vb code is:

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Data.OleDb
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports System.Configuration
    Imports System.Web.Mvc
    Public Class TimeOffAllByUser
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

            Dim vusername() As String

            vusername = Split(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, "\", , CompareMethod.Text)
            'TextBox1.Text = (vusername(1))

        End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Just to check can you change like this to understand whether this is the problem with quotes? QueryStringField='Split(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, "\",,CompareMethod.Text)'

Comment: Nope - didn't work.  Thanks for the suggestion. Also tried:

Comment: Oops - Also tried:  QueryStringField='Split(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, &quot;\&quot;,,CompareMethod.Text)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think the problem is that you are using QueryStringParameter and in the querystring field you are using expressions, which might not work. What you can do instead is

Change your QueryStringParameter to normal Parameter

```
<asp:Parameter Name="username"  />
```

In your DataSource declarcation add selecting event

```
OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting"
```

In the Selecting event assign the parameter value

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Selecting(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e As SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs )

     Dim vusername() As String
     vusername = Split(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, "\", , CompareMethod.Text)
     e.Command.Parameters["@username"].Value=vusername(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm using vb, and I'm having problems translating this from c to vb.  Can you help me?

Comment: It works!  I just had to tweak it a little.  e.Command.Parameters("@username").Value = vusername(1)   - Parenthesis not brackets.  Thanks so much!!!